# What's the best practice for restoring the trace id when a 3rd party integration interrupts the trace?

Tags: microservices, observability

When we receive an HTTP call, we create a new trace id, and pass it to all microservices involved in dealing with that request and the subrequests that result from it.

This works fine until a certain flow involves calling an external service that provides the response asynchronously via a webhook call (so we call them, they reply with 202, and then they call our webhook endpoint when their response is ready): that webhook call is treated as a brand new HTTP call, it gets a new trace id, and so our trace is now broken in 2 different traces.

What's the best practice for restoring the previous interrupted trace?

Comment: As per the answer from opeonikute. Assuming you have any control of either returned data or webhook url per invocation. You can either add the trace context carrier to the webhook callback url or as part of any input data that is also part of the output. Then restore the context in the webhook handler.
Last resort would be to contact the third party and ask them to forward the trace header you send them back to you, and hope they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using [context propagation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/propagation/). This is a technique to move data between services/processes. Consider the example below of the propagation of context to a worker process in OpenTelemetry:

```
// app.js
const { W3CTraceContextPropagator } = require("@opentelemetry/core");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const parentSpan = tracer.startSpan('send_to_queue');

  // inject the context into the carrier object and send
  // into the queue
  const propagator = new W3CTraceContextPropagator();
  let carrier = {};

  propagator.inject(
      opentelemetry.trace.setSpanContext(opentelemetry.ROOT_CONTEXT,         
      parentSpan.spanContext()),
      carrier,
      opentelemetry.defaultTextMapSetter
  );

  queue.send({foo: 'bar', carrier });

  parentSpan.end();
});

// worker.js
channel.consume(queue, async function(payload) {
  // Extract the context from the queue payload and start
  // a child span. Ensures the new span is sent to the
  // original parent span.
  const data = JSON.parse(payload.content.toString());
  const parentContext =         opentelemetry.propagation.extract(opentelemetry.ROOT_CONTEXT, data.carrier);
  opentelemetry.context.with(parentContext, async () => {
    tracer.startActiveSpan(
      'process_queue_item',
      async (span) => {
        await makeExternalRequest("http://google.com");
        span.end();
    });
  });
});
```

In the same vein, you can propagate context to the external service and insert spans there which will be a part of the same trace. Some examples of doing this in other tracing tools are:

1. In Datadog for NodeJS, the [trace API](https://datadoghq.dev/dd-trace-js/interfaces/tracer.html#inject) can also inject context into a carrier for cross-process propagation, using the text-map setter:

   ```
    // app.js
    // inject context
    const opentracing = require("opentracing");
    const tracer = require('dd-trace').init();

    const span = tracer.scope().active();
    const carrier = {};

    tracer.inject(span, opentracing.FORMAT_TEXT_MAP, carrier);

    // worker.js
    // extract context and start child span
    const parent = tracer.extract(opentracing.FORMAT_TEXT_MAP, payload.carrier);

    const childSpan = tracer.startSpan("the.child", { childOf: parent });

    // do the work here

    childSpan.end();
   ```
2. Honeycomb has specific documentation for inter-process propagation.

   ```
    // app.js
    const beeline = require("honeycomb-beeline")();

    const traceContext = beeline.honeycomb.marshalTraceContext(beeline.getTraceContext());

    payload.traceContext = traceContext;

    // worker.js
    const { traceId, parentSpanId, dataset, customContext } = beeline.honeycomb.unmarshalTraceContext(payload.traceContext);

    const trace = startTrace({ name }, traceId, parentSpanId, dataset, customContext);

    beeline.finishTrace(trace);
   ```

Comment: The problem with this solution, if I understand it correctly, is that it implies that I'm in control of the external service and can restore the trace. However this is not my case: the external service is a 3rd party, it's not under our control, and they call us back via a webhook